# CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL not work on device

Tags: ios, fonts, download

I am trying to use `CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler` to download a font. As same as the example provided by Apple: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Listings/DownloadFont_ViewController_m.html

It works fine, and I can display the downloaded font in my application, but after I restart my application I can not create the UIFont with `fontWithName:size:`, and `[UIFont familyNames]` does not include the downloaded font. To solve this problem, I record the font path and use `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` to register the font when start the application. After doing this, everything is OK on simulator, **but not works on device!!!** Help!!!

Comment: why don't you include font(.ttf) file into your project and use it.

Comment: After downloading your font you have to include your font in "info" tag of project.Go to info-->add('fonts Provided By Application')-->AddFonts

Comment: @SahebSingh I use this in iOS project, the font file will make the package too large. And I do not find "fonts Provided By Application", you mean "Application fonts resource path"?

Comment: Select your ProjectFile in XCOde-->Fo to "Info"-->In "Custom iOS Target Properties"-->Add Key "Fonts Provided By Application"-->And Add your fonts name in it.

Better Go through this [link](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem is that `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` will fail when the font file url is something like: `/var/mobile/.../XXX.ttc`, and after I fixed the url to be `file:///var/mobile/.../XXX.ttc`, everything will be OK.